# Passing arguments when using redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails controller, in one method I do a `redirect_to` to another path (i.e. another method). I want to also pass arguments from the first method, so that the second method can use them. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

for example:

```
redirect_to new_user_url(@user)
```

You can receive @user in your new user page.

or

```
redirect_to action_name_resource_path(resource_object, {:param_1 => 'value_1', :param_2 => 'value_2'})
```

or

```
redirect_to new_users_path(request.parameters)
```

Comment: In your first example, what is `new_user_url`? Is it the name of a controller method, a view, or a path?

Comment: And in your second example, what is `resource_object`?

Comment: new_user is path that define in route.rb for example - match '/users/new/:id' => "users#new", :as => "new_user". if if you want to call new_user then we write new_user_url and pass argument

Comment: Okay, and what is `resource_object` in the second example?

Comment: If you are using RESTful resources then you can follow the second example. for more info - see - http://www.techques.com/question/1-1430247/Passing-parameters-in-rails-redirect_to